# Is there a pattern to Yonasan Ben Uziel's introduction to mitzvos?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mitzvah, targumin

Starting with the dibros, YbU introduces some mitzvos with the words 'Ami bnei Yisrael" and I don't see the pattern as to when he does and when he doesn't. Anyone have an idea which ones deserve this intro?

Additionally, on at least one occasion it is "Ami beis Yisrael" (Vayikra 25:36 - immediately followed with an "ami bnei Yisrael" intro in the next verse).

Comment: That Targum is probably not Yonatan Ben Uziel's: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum_Pseudo-Jonathan. This puzzled me too!

Comment: here is Yisro http://targum.info/pj/pjex18-20.htm and here is Mishpatim http://targum.info/pj/pjex21-24.htm in English Targum Pseudo-Yonasan. Search for my people in Chrome and it will highlight each instance in yellow. Then it might be easier to identify the pattern.

Comment: The pattern I've spotted so far: beginning of new idea / section, where it is directed towards second person ("you") as opposed to third person ("he"). Thus this gets no such intro: Whosoever smiteth a son or a daughter of Israel, so as to cause death. But this gets the intro: If thou lend money to (one of) My people, to (one of) the humble of My people.

Comment: @joshwaxman but what about the second verse? "When thou shalt acquire a Hebrew slave..."

Comment: @joshwaxman also the beginning of chapter 23 says it many times, all on the topic of judicial process.

Comment: Second verse already has its own intro, with no midrashic interjection by Targum yonatan to require a new intro. In ch 23, if all those are stated in second person, then maybe the midrashic interjections for each are sufficient to deal with each as a new section.

Comment: @joshwaxman Why not post an answer?  It's a good theory.

Comment: @joshwaxman is second verse's intro first verse? wouldn't that serve as a universal intro? In 23 I'm not seeing many midrashic interjections, certainly not before every verse that has the intro. Also on that page, last paragraph in 22 , what about first fruits and first born, that's in second person, and distinct, also treifah.

Comment: does it resume after that in the next sidra?

Comment: @joshwaxman I found one other instance in Ki tisah, by Reiyah

Comment: @joshwaxman also in kedoshim, a few times.